# Looking for regex to match before and after a number

Tags: regex, nintex-workflow

Given the string

> 170905-CBM-238.pdf

I'm trying to match `170905-CBM` and `.pdf` so that I can replace/remove them and be left with `238`.

I've searched and found pieces that work but can't put it all together.
This-> `(.*-)` will match the first section and
This-> `(.[^/.]+$)` will match the last section

But I can't figure out how to tie them together so that it matches everything before, including the second dash and everything after, including the period (or the extension) but does not match the numbers between.

help :) and thank you for your kind consideration.

Comment: Try [`^.*-([0-9]+)\.[^.]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/5d3pfL/1).

Comment: that appears to match everything - I need to have it not match the number (and the extension may not always be pdf) --cheers

Comment: If you just want to extract `238`, why match anything else? Just do `-(\d+)\.pdf$`.

Comment: Possibility of `.PDF` vs `.pdf`? Any number of digits prior to the extension? What flavor of regex?

Comment: I'm using nintex to match and replace so need to match everything else so I can replace with "".  Your solution returns the first section, having replaced everything/including after the last dash

Comment: Can't you just do two regex replace actions in a row, one to strip the prefix and one to strip the suffix?

Comment: yes - eventually I just added in two steps in the workflow and that will suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options to achieve what you need in Nintex.

If you use *Extract* operation, use `(?<=^.*-)\d+(?=\.[^.]*$)` as *Pattern*.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E.*-%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D%5C.%5B%5E.%5D*%24%29&i=170905-CBM-238.pdf).

**Details**

- `(?<=^.*-)` - a positive lookbehind requiring, immediately to the left of the current location, the start of string (`^`), then any 0+ chars other than LF as many as possible up to the last occurrence of `-` and the subsequent subpatterns
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?=\.[^.]*$)` - a positive lookahead requiring, immediately to the right of the current location, the presence of a `.` and 0+ chars other than `.` up to the end of the string.

If you use *Replace text* operation, use

*Pattern*: `^.*-([0-9]+)\.[^.]+$`
*Replacement text*: `$1`

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E.*-%28%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%5C.%5B%5E.%5D%2B%24&i=170905-CBM-238.pdf&r=%241) (the *Context* tab shows the result of the replacement).

**Details**

- `^` - a start of string anchor
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than LF up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns...
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more ASCII digits
- `\.` - a literal `.`
- `[^.]+` - 1 or more chars other than `.`
- `$` -  end of string.

The replacement `$1` references the value stored in Group 1.

Comment: Awesome! both methods worked and truly appreciate the added Details!

Comment: FYI: I opted for replace because it yields a simple variable while extract requires a collection variable

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ninetex regex, but a `sed` type regex:

```
$ echo "170905-CBM-238.pdf" | sed -E 's/^.*-([0-9]*)\.[^.]*$/\1/'
238
```

Same works in Perl:

```
$ echo "170905-CBM-238.pdf" | perl -pe 's/^.*-([0-9]*)\.[^.]*$/$1/'
238
```

Comment: Apparently nintex uses .NET regex, i.e. basically Perl flavor.

Comment: In Perl you're supposed to use `$1` in the replacement part. Maybe `$1` works in .NET replacement strings, too (it does in JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks for the response but tried both and no joy :(